# Insert PHP code in shortcode using do_shortcode()

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am trying to insert PHP code in a shortcode.

For now it look likes this:

```
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[to_like][/to_like]'); ?>

<?php do_action('single_spot_after_content', get_the_ID(), 'after_content'); ?>
```

I have tried several plugins to combine this to one shortcode (PHP shortcode plugin, Advanced Custom fields, etc.)

This is what I want to accomplish, but it is not working:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[to_like]<?php do_action('single_spot_after_content', get_the_ID(), 'after_content'); ?>
[/to_like]'); ?>
```

In the front-end the user can select the value through a dropdown field --> for example 10% discount (this is going to be displayed when a visitor likes the box). The theme has a special markup field (you can create custom submission fields) where %% is going to be changed by the chosen value from the customer. This value is going to be displayed on the website (singe listing page).

How can I implement this? This is so vital for the website.

Comment: This doesn't seem odd to you? <?php echo do_shortcode('[to_like]<?php

Comment: #skrilled 

I am using a plugin called like2unlock but this plugin can only be used (without extreme PHP knowledge) with the shortcode [to_like] [/to_like]. For example [to_like]10% DISCOUNT[/to_like] will output , when you like it, 10 discount. But I am using spotfinder and this theme has a built in searchfield and submissionfield creator.

<?php do_action('single_spot_after_content', get_the_ID(), 'after_content'); ?> This code will show every custom made submission field. I am trying to wrap this in the shortcode of the plugin (like2get)

Comment: You are confusing code and strings that look like code. They are not the same thing!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[to_like]' . do_action('single_spot_after_content', get_the_ID(), 'after_content') . '[/to_like]' ); ?>
```

Comment: Did not work. I have put the following code in the markup field of the custom submission field: 
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[to_like]%%[/to_like]' ); ?>


But I it is outputting nothing on the single listing page

With Chrome inspect element it is showing me this, which means it is disabling the code:

<div class="submission-field-select">

 <!--?php echo do_shortcode( '[to_like]%%[/to_like]' ); ?-->
</div>

Comment: That doesn't look right.  It needs to be `<?php`  and not `<!--?php`.

Comment: This is the description of the markup field:

This is the markup that is displayed in your front end. You can use the variable %% to display the chosen value.
For example to display a website you can type "Website: %%" where %% will be replaced with the chosen value if provided.
You can also use %_*VAL_% to multiply an element based on the value. For example if your field is a number, use "%_*VAL_% ELEMENT" to multiple the string ELEMENT by the amount of times the user has chosen.

Maybe this field is not accepting php code

Comment: Yes it is very likely that this field is not accepting PHP code.  You can test this theory by trying something more simple, I recommend trying: `<?php echo "hello"; ?>` and `<? echo "hello"; ?>`, separately to see if either approach works.

Comment: No it is not working, it blocks the php code.I am not at all a developer. So I think this would be a dead end.....

Comment: That proves you can't use PHP code there, sorry.  I hope this answer helped answer your question though, please accept if so.

Comment: Yep, thanx all of you for your effort. It seems I need to hire a freelancer to tweak this. Again thanx your help. I know where not to search anymore.

Comment: Not sure why I am getting downvotes without feedback considering I helped the questioner.